# How to include the paddle in the pong game?

Tags: processing, pong

I have some problems with my code, which I can't really figure it out. So I started programming the pong game but I don't know how to include the paddle, so the ball bounces off when hitting the paddle but goes through, when it isn't. I've tried if- & else statements and a constrain function for this but it didn't work somehow.

My code:

```
float ballxposition = 0; float ballyposition = 0; float speedx = 0;
float speedy = 0;

void setup() {  size(1024, 768);  speedx = 10;  speedy = 10; }

void draw() {  background(255);  fill(128);  rectMode(CENTER); 
rect(mouseX, 730, 250, 20);

fill(0, 0, 255);  ellipse(ballxposition, ballyposition, 30, 30);

ballxposition = ballxposition + speedx;  ballyposition = ballyposition
+ speedy;

if (ballxposition>width||ballxposition<0) {

speedx = speedx * -1;  }

if (ballyposition>height||ballyposition<0) {

speedy = speedy * -1;  } }
```

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: currently you're drawing the paddle using hardcoded values. same way you made `ballxposition`/`ballyposition` you do create variables for the paddle position and dimensions. the x position will be equal to `mouseX`. (you could rename `ballxposition` to `ballXPosition` to keep things more [conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case). Because you know the paddle position and size you can write an if condition to check if the ball is within the bounds of the ball. if it is simply flip the ball velocity or better yet, remember and restore the last valid...

Comment: ...position and calculate the reflection direction. if a ball is hit you reflect the ball based on the angle it hit the paddle, restoring to the position before the paddle collision before setting the new velocity

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation, George. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this youtube video worth watching
it's created by a guy called Dan Shiffman his website is The Coding Train: http://thecodingtrain.com

**Coding Challenge #67: Pong!**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIrC5Qcb2G4

I find his coding challenges very useful

Comment: Yes it is indeed. Started watching his videos recently.